# How to reconcile LDR's and Photoelectricity?

Tags: electricity, photons, electrons, electrical-resistance, photoelectric-effect

I am currently studying high school level physics. First I learned that photoelectric experiments show that increasing the intensity of the incident light doesn't increase the energy gained by the electrons, according to Einstein's photoeletric equation $$E_{\text{max KE}}=hf-\phi.$$

However, today I learned (in a different topic, namely electricity) that the resistance of an LDR or Light Dependent Resistor decreases with increasing intensity of incident light. The explanation given in my textbook is that as you increase the intensity of the light, the light is more energetic and so is able to provide more electrons in the LDR with enough energy to break the bonds holding them to their atoms, creating more free electrons which therefore improves the conductivity of the LDR, reducing its resistivity.

My problem is that this seems to contradict what I learned earlier about photoelectricity, i.e. that the energy gained by the electrons is not dependent on the intensity of the light.

The only way I could reconcile this in my mind was to assume that LDR's cannot be made of metal. If this is the case then it would make sense because as far as I know the photoelectric effect only applies to metals.

Comment: Typical LDR is cadmium sulphide (or was?), but other semiconductors are also photoconductive. Internal photoelectric effect produces charge carriers. I do not understand the question.

Comment: @Pieter: Thank you for your comment. But why is it that for the 'internal photoelectric effect' the energy gained by the electrons is dependent on the intensity of the incident light, whereas for the normal photoelectric effect it only depends on the frequency of the light? I hope that clarifies.

Comment: No, the number of charge carriers created is proportional to the light intensity. Same as the number of electrons emitted into the vacuum in the ordinary external photoelectric effect. Ah, now I get it: in a vacuum, this constitutes the photocurrent, independent of voltage (in the right range). In a semiconductor, it reduces the resistivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is that the conductivity of the semiconductor used in an LDR doesn't depend on the energy of the electrons freed by the incident light, but by the number of them that are freed. And the number of electrons excited by the photoelectric effect **is** proportional to the intensity of the incident light (assuming the light has sufficient energy per photon to excite an electron into the desired state).